# How to return data from a aysnc/await function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, async-await

I am trying to return data from my Mongo DB collection,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, age: Number, email: String });
const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
Customer.create({ name: 'A', age: 30, email: 'a@foo.bar' });

const data = Customer.find()
                .then( ( data) => {
                    return data;
                }, (error) => {
                    return error ;
                });

console.log("data : " + data);

// async/await 

var data1 = (async function () {
    const data = await Customer.find();
    return data ;
})();

console.log("Data1 : " + data1);
```

And I am getting output as

```
data : [object Promise]
Data1 : [object Promise]
```

But I am trying to see `name: 'A', age: 30, email: 'a@foo.bar'` object in the response data.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: `Customer.find().then(data => console.log(data))`. There's your `data`. Put your code that needs it there.

Comment: @deceze, But I want to assign the data to a variable ?

Comment: It *is* in a variable: `data`. Inside the `then` callback.

Comment: @deceze, but after result, I am supposed to have data instead of object Promise, I am missing something here.

Comment: Please read the duplicate.